# How to show Not a Free Module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, noncommutative-algebra

Let $\mathbb K$ be a field, $A= \mathbb K [x,y]$ and $ M = Ax + Ay$. prove that $M$ is *NOT* a free module!

Answer (score 4):

Hint: prove it isn't generated by a single element.  Then prove that any two elements are linearly dependent.

More details:

You can show that $M$ is not generated by a single generator using the fact that $x$ and $y$ are irreducible in the UFD $A$.  If $f$ generates $M$ then $f$ divides $x$ and also $f$ divides $y$.  Since these are distinct irreducible elements (so coprime) $f$ must be a constant, but then f is not in $A$ so this is impossible.

To show that any two elements of $M$ are linearly dependent let $f,g \in M$ be nonzero (otherwise we are done).  Then $fg-gf=0$.  Notice that this is a linear combination of $f$ and $g$ with (nonzero) coefficients in $A$ since $f$ and $g$ are also in $A$.

Comment: Sorry ... but I am not that familiar with the problem solving in Module Theory. Just started reading theoretical part! So can you please give me detailed solution??

Comment: Okkay..Since $\mathbb K$ is a field , So, $\mathbb K[x,y]$ is a UFD. Also, each of $x$ & $y$ are irreducibles in $A$ . This I've understood! Now, if $f$ generates $M$ then, any element of $M$ is some scalar times $f$ . Right??

Comment: Yes, where scalar means element of $A$.

Comment: I added the rest of the details in case you are still stuck.

Comment: & again..elements of $A$ means polynomial in $x$ & $y$ .with coefficients from $\mathbb K$. Right?? But, after that..how can you say $f$ divides $x$ & $y$ both??

Comment: We have $af=x$ where $a\in A=\mathbb{k}[x,y]$ and $f\in M\subset A$.  So this is exactly what it means for $f$ to divide $x$.  Similarly for $y$.

Comment: Ohhh ho..okkay okkay... I got it now!!... Yep.. after this the linear dependence argument is fine!! Thank you..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13885/discussion-between-user86511-and-seth)